# How to convert only one (out of several) numeric columns to one decimal point

Tags: format

I have a dataframe with 3 columns.  The column 'machinery' represents word counts, 'cum_sum' is a rolling total count of the column titled 'machinery' and 'cum_pct' is the rolling cumulative percent total.

I have tried pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format but this shows 1 decimal place for all columns.

How to I show the column 'cum_pct' to one decimal place, not changing the decimal place for the other 2 columns?[image]

Comment: Please [tag a language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) so the right people can find your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
# Generate rolling total of the column machinery in data frame 'tokens_test' like above:

tokens_test['cum_sum'] = tokens_test['machinery'].cumsum()
tokens_test['cum_pct'] = ((100.0*tokens_test['cum_sum']/tokens_test["machinery"].sum()))    

# Apply formatting:

cols = ['cum_pct']
tokens_test[cols] = tokens_test[cols].applymap('{:,.1f}'.format)
```

[image]